# How to parametrize a posterior to use it as a prior in Bayesian statistics?

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, prior, hierarchical-bayesian, parameterization

In my problem, I have two sets of parameters, $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, and two datasets $d_1,d_2$ that constrain them with a known likelihood function. There is a certain 'hierarchy' in the model: the likelihood is separable and one only depends on $\theta_1$: $$\mathcal{L}(d_1,d_2|\theta_1,\theta_2) = \mathcal{L}(d_2|\theta_1,\theta_2)\mathcal{L}(d_1|\theta_1).$$ I want to sample from the joint posterior
$$p(\theta_1, \theta_2 | d_1, d_2).$$
Unfortunately, due to the high cost of evaluating $\mathcal{L}(d_1|\theta_1)$, it is not practical to directly sample this posterior. I am lucky: the likelihood of $d_1$ is only a function of $\theta_1$. Because of that, I want to split up this posterior in a hierarchical way like so:
$$p(\theta_1, \theta_2 | d_1, d_2) \propto \mathcal{L}(d_2,d_1|\theta_1,\theta_2)\pi(\theta_1,\theta_2)\\
=\mathcal{L}(d_2|\theta_1,\theta_2) (\mathcal{L}(d_1|\theta_1)\pi(\theta_1))\pi(\theta_2).$$

This suggests doing the sampling in two steps: first sampling from $p(\theta_1|d_1)=\mathcal{L}(d_1|\theta_1)\pi(\theta_1)$ and subsequently using this as a prior on the full posterior. Computationally, this would be much preferred.

However, in practice, my $p(\theta_1|d_1)$ is not analytically calculable, so instead it is sampled, with e.g. MCMC. But if you only have samples, how do you use this as a prior in an MCMC run of $p(\theta_1,\theta_2|d_1,d_2)$? You have to parameterize this prior somehow, right?

A simple way would be to assume that $p(\theta_1|d_1)$ is a multivariate Gaussian, with a mean and covariance matrix derived from the sampled MCMC chains, but this is not always a reasonable assumption. If parametrizing is indeed necessary, how do you do this if the posterior is non-gaussian, for example a banana-shape, in some parameters?

Comment: I think in a typical hierarchical model the priors for $\theta_i$ would involve hyperparameters such as $\psi$. The joint prior for all the unknowns would have the form $p(\psi)\,\prod_i p(\theta_i|\psi)$. This prior induces dependence between $\theta_i$ and $\theta_j$. It is via this dependence that the information $d_i$ informs $\theta_j$ for example. Is this the sort of model you have in mind?

Comment: Not exactly, in my case the priors $\pi(\theta_i)$ are already fully known and independent of parameters. Perhaps, this is not a strict hierarchical model then, sorry... I'll edit the question a bit!

Comment: Okay, I see. I have a question: If evaluating $\mathcal{L}(d_1|\theta_1)$ is so expensive, how can you sample from $p(\theta_1|d_1)$?

Comment: Two reasons, firstly because $\theta_1$ has only a dimension of 4, but $\theta_2$ has a dimension of 12. And secondly, because I could reuse this $p(\theta_1|d_1)$: as a next step I want to compare the posteriors for a set of, say 100 different $d_2$'s.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't see how that answers my question. I must be missing something. Good luck.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear! I will rewrite my comment a bit below

Comment: The problem is not that evaluating $\mathcal{L}(d_1|\theta_1)$ is prohibitively expensive, it is just that $\theta_1$ has only a dimension of 4, but $\theta_2$ has a dimension of 12, so that makes converging the mcmc chain on only $\theta_1$ much faster than having to converge on both $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ simultaneously.  And secondly, for a later stage of my modeling (not part of this question) I could reuse this $p(\theta_1|d_1)$, for example to compare posteriors of 100 different $d_2$'s.